# Google Drive Android api - Downloading db file from drive

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-android-api

I am using the below code for downloading an already uploaded sqlite db file from google drive to the data/data/packagename/databases folder, but when the method completes, I am seeing a db corruption warning message logged in logcat and also all the data on the device for the app is overwritten and shows up blank, upon opening the app.

```
mfile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, mResultsAdapter.getItem(0).getDriveId());
                    mfile.openContents(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);

--mfile is an instance of DriveFile

final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsOpenedCallback = new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResult(ContentsResult result)
    {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess())
        {
            FileUtils.appendLog(getApplicationContext(), Tag + "-onResult", "Error opening file");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if (GetFileFromDrive(result))
            {
                        //FileUtils.Restore(getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPrefHelper.EditSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.PREFS_DO_RESTORE, false);
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

private boolean GetFileFromDrive(ContentsResult result)
{
    Contents contents = result.getContents();
    //InputStreamReader rda = new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
    FileOutputStream outStream;
    String currLine;
    boolean restoreSuccess = false;

    File sourceDbFile = BackupDBBeforeDeletion();

    if(sourceDbFile != null)
        sourceDbFile.delete();

    try
    {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(Constants.DB_NAME));
        while ((currLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            outStream.write(currLine.getBytes());
        }

        outStream.flush();

        reader.close();
        outStream.close();
        restoreSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO: Log exception
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO: Log Exception
    }

    return restoreSuccess;
}
```

When the method GetFileFromDrive completes, a db corruption shows up on LogCat and all the existing data on the app's datanase file (sqlite db) is gone.

Please help, as I have verified that the drive uploaded sqlite db file is correct and well formed, by downloading the same and opening it up in Sqlite Browser. It's the download from drive that is not working.

Comment: Try writing the file to a local file first (not the DB file path) and make sure that's not corrupt. Then copying the file into place. Maybe SQLite is corrupting it - it's trying to be read/write while you're writing the file. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, that is part of my problem, as when I tried doing exactly what you have suggested, the db file formed on that other path, but the **db was blank**, even though I know there is data in there on the drive version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally fix my own issue, by replacing the **file.openContents** with **file.open** and setting a result call back with **DriveContents** result back rather than **ContentsResult**.

Also, used the DriveContents to set an InputStream on the same (initially opened in Mode_Read_Only in open method) and then writing it out into a physical ".db" file on the data base path location.

Now, the database doesn't get corrupted and restores data successfully.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually fixed and did not just work once? I think I am seeing a lot of this. The files seem to be fine locally -- the same client is able to read the files back in. However, they seem to get corrupted on drive and on other clients. That's why I am relatively confident it's not a problem with my app... :-/

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the .db file uploaded to google drive and then opened it up in Sqlite browser to verify the data. Both the file itself and the data within were intact on the drive version, when uploaded from the app. The same when restored back into the app overwrote the local sqlite db and correctly restored the data. I have run this code many a times now and the read-write to drive works fine now.

Comment: Did you test this on different devices? For me, the local data is always fine, but the data in the google drive web interface (and other clients) gets corrupted (in my case, it's JSON, so it's quite obvious sometimes).

Comment: The usage of the db file is specific to be within my app and the drive's appfolder. I don't need a web interface or anything to use that file anywhere else.

Comment: The cross device corruption issue that Stefan is referring to has been fixed (https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3696). Please comment on that bug report if you are seeing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not working for me. The sqlite files I got from google drive is more longer than I saved in google drive. That, probably, happen because you are using a Buffereader class and the method readline that reads data in char. 
In my project and experience this solutions does not work, I got a corrupted sqlite db.
So... I save sqlite db in google drive in byte so **I read from google drive the same sqlite db in byte, using BufferedInputStream.
This works perfectly for me:

```
DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(contents.getInputStream());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesread = 0;
                FileOutputStream outStream;

                /*if(currentDB != null)
                    currentDB.delete();*/

                try
                {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(currentDB);
                    while( (bytesread = bis.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        outStream.write(buffer,0,bytesread);
                    }

                    outStream.flush();
                    bis.close();
                    outStream.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG,e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG,e.getMessage());
                }
                finally {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"Data from Google Drive restored successfully." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                contents.discard(mGoogleApiClient);
```