# Read from sqlite db in Drive and write it to local db - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am developing an application which requires sqlite database to be backed up to Google Drive (which I accomplished). Now I want to restore that database back into my application and load it at runtime from SD card.

I am reading the contents of database from Google Drive using android-demo/RetrieveContentsActivity on GitHub and I am using the following code to write it back in my database

**ListView onItemClickListener**

```
               Drive.DriveApi
                    .getFile(api,
                            mResultsAdapter.getItem(position).getDriveId())
                    .openContents(api, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                    .setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);
```

**ResultCallBack**

```
final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsOpenedCallback = new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            return;
        }

        if (GetFileFromDrive(result)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File restored",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

**GetFileFromDrive**

```
private boolean GetFileFromDrive(ContentsResult result) {
    Contents contents = result.getContents();
    InputStream mInput = contents.getInputStream();
    OutputStream mOutput;
    boolean restoreSuccess = false;

    try {
        mOutput = new FileOutputStream(getDatabasePath(DB_NAME));
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }

        mOutput.flush();

        mInput.close();
        mOutput.close();
        restoreSuccess = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO: Log exception
        Log.e("error_filenotfound", "" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: Log Exception
        Log.e("error_io", "" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return restoreSuccess;
}
```

The problem is that it deletes the already existing data in my sqlite and empties my sqlite completely. I have tried to find this issue on Google but none came close to helping me.

This guy - [Google Drive Android api - Downloading db file from drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532869/google-drive-android-api-downloading-db-file-from-drive) - is trying to do the same but he says that he replaced `openContents` with `open`. I tried that but it gives an error that `The method open(GoogleApiClient, int, null) is undefined for the type DriveFile`.

Any sort of help will be appreciated, please. I have been stuck on this for almost a week now and I am getting annoyed.

Comment: Wow. Negative point for asking a question. That too without feedback on what I should have done.

Comment: They changed the Drive APIs in Google Play Service v 7.x. If you are still using openContents() instead of open(), then you must be on an old version. The current one is 7.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you downloaded you DB to Drive.
Now, how we get it inside you app:
This example contain FragmentActivity, with GUI. But, you can easy adapt it it to silent download.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SUCCESS:
                // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    finish();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    //Toast.makeText(this, R.string.pref_data_drive_import_success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    DriveId driveId = data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

                    DriveFile file = driveId.asDriveFile();

                    processDriveFile(file);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.pref_data_drive_import_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());

        if (!result.hasResolution()){
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
            finish();
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");

        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                //.setMimeType(new String[] { "application/x-sqlite3" })
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }

    }

@Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }
```

Now, we do check, if selected file is our database and replase it

```
private void processDriveFile(DriveFile file){
        Log.i(TAG, "processDriveFile started");
        file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult) {
                if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import DB error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                    return;
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");

                DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();

                InputStream inputStream = driveContents.getInputStream();

                String dbDir = context.getDatabasePath("oldDbName.db").getParent();
                String newFileName = "newDbName.db";

                Log.i(TAG, "dbDir = " + dbDir);

                // Deletion previous versions of new DB file from drive
                File file = new File(dbDir + "/" + newFileName);
                if (file.exists()){
                    Log.i(TAG, "newDbName.db EXISTS");
                    if (file.delete()){
                        Log.i(TAG, "newDbName.db DELETING old file....");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "newDbName.db Something went wrong with deleting");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import DB error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                try {
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    try {
                        try {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                            int read;

                            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                            }
                            output.flush();
                        } finally {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import DB error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import DB error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import DB error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                // Check if file really match our DB
                // Connection it to custom SqliteOpenHelper
                ImportDBManager importDBManager = new ImportDBManager(context);
                importDBManager.open();
                // We have some System table in DB with 1 row in it for this goal
                // So, we check if there is data in it
                List<DataModelSystem> dataModelSystem = importDBManager.getSystemSingleRow(1);
                importDBManager.close();
                if (dataModelSystem.size() > 0){
                    Log.i(TAG, "DB MATCH!");
                    String mainDbName = context.getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DB_NAME).toString();
                    String newDbName = context.getDatabasePath(ImportDatabaseHelper.DB_NAME).toString();
                    File oldDbFile = new File(mainDbName);
                    File newDbFile = new File(newDbName);

                    if (newDbFile.exists()){
                        Log.i(TAG, "newDbName.db EXISTS");
                        if (oldDbFile.delete()){
                            Log.i(TAG, "newDbName.db DELETING old file....");
                            try {
                                copyFile(newDbFile, oldDbFile);
                                Log.i(TAG, "success! New database");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import OK!!!!1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import DB error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.i(TAG, "fail! old database will remain");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                finish();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "newDbName.db Something went wrong with deleting");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import DB error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "db not Match!");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Import DB error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
        finish();
    }

    // Replacing old file
    private static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        Log.i(TAG, "src = " + src.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.i(TAG, "dst = " + dst.getAbsolutePath());
        FileInputStream var2 = new FileInputStream(src);
        FileOutputStream var3 = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        byte[] var4 = new byte[1024];

        int var5;
        while((var5 = var2.read(var4)) > 0) {
            var3.write(var4, 0, var5);
        }

        var2.close();
        var3.close();
    }
```

It is 100% working

Answer (score 0):

Nobody's gonna run and debug your code. Here are a few points to help:

1/ Assuming your app uploaded your DB file (GooDrive does not care if it is DB or anything else - just a byte stream). Record/save it's DriveId - it should look like "*DriveId:CAES........*"

2/ check if the file in GooDrive (drive.google.com) has the size you expect. You can also use third party SQLite web app to check the state of your DB file in the Drive (make sure you created/uploaded it with correct MIME type).

3/ In you Android app, pass your saved DriveId to this method:

```
  private static GoogleApiClient mGAC;
  ...
  /*******************************************************************
   * get file contents
   * @param dId  file driveId
   */
  static void read(DriveId dId) {
    byte[] buf = null;
    if (mGAC != null && mGAC.isConnected() && dId != null) {
      DriveFile df = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGAC, dId);
      df.open(mGAC, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
                               .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveContentsResult rslt) {
          if ((rslt != null) && rslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            DriveContents cont = rslt.getDriveContents();
            byte[] buf = UT.is2Bytes(cont.getInputStream());
            int size = buf.length;
            cont.discard(mGAC);    // or cont.commit();  they are equiv if READONLY
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

4/ check the size/state/content of the byte buffer you downloaded. You can write it back to the DB file as well.

These steps should get you closer to resolving your error.

Good Luck